# Image from Amazon S3 Bucket didn't display in first request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am facing a unique problem and I am not able to understand the reason behind this.

I have Amazon S3 account and I create bucket where I kept my uploaded images. I am using following code to retrieve the image. My issue is unique because when I am retrieving the image in first request then it is not showing anything on webpage but the image is getting retrieved after subsequent request and display to webpage.

I am not able to understand the reason.

**Angular JS Code**

```
$scope.retrieveImage = function ()
{
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: "MY_ACCESS_KEY",
        secretAccessKey: "MY_SECRET_KEY"
    });

    AWS.config.region = "BUCKET_REGION";

    var bucketInstance = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {
        Bucket: "BUCKET_NAME",
        Key: "FILE_NAME"
    }
    bucketInstance.getObject(params, function (err, file) {
        if (file) {
            $scope.imgSrc = "data:" + file.ContentType + ";base64," + encode(file.Body);           
        } else {
            console.log('error::', err);
        }
    });
}

function encode(data) {
    var str = data.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + String.fromCharCode(b) }, '');
    return btoa(str).replace(/.{76}(?=.)/g, '$&\n');
}
```

Comment: The issue is probably with AngularJs, you test that the image is retrieved outside of AngularJs or you could monitor network traffic with Chrome Developer tooling, you are likely to find the image is returned from Amazon S3 with each request and that your AngularJs view is just not refreshing correctly

Comment: You are correct. The issue was with Angular JS. After applying $scope.$apply() it starts showing image on first load.

Comment: glad you figured it out, I added my comment as an answer since it was the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably with AngularJs, confirm that the image is retrieved outside of AngularJs or you could monitor network traffic with Chrome Developer tooling, you are likely to find the image is returned from Amazon S3 with each request and that your AngularJs view is just not refreshing correctly

Answer (score 1):

You should read more about [S3 Data Consystency Model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html)

> Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new
>   objects in your S3 bucket in all regions with one caveat. The caveat
>   is that if you make a HEAD or GET request to the key name (to find if
>   the object exists) before creating the object, Amazon S3 provides
>   eventual consistency for read-after-write.
>
> Amazon S3 offers eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES
>   in all regions.

It means there are some lag/delay after you get put succeed code.